# Jquery hide and show animation cancel

Tags: jquery, hide, show

First of all:

- i'm trying to create a "Connect 4" game
- `#send` is a button id="send" html

The Problem is, when I launch the web page
the `.grid` is hidden but when I click on
the `#send` button the `show()` animation execute for 0.5
and then disapear...

At first I thought the problem was from the .ready() function but I was wrong.

searching for some hint.
Just beginning at jQuery.

```
$.fn.puissance4 = function(x,y) {
    $(document).ready(() => {

        var color_count = 0;
        // $(document).on('click', function(){
        //  $('body').show('.grid')
        // })
        // Genere le container     
        $('body').append('<div class="grid"></div>');
        $('.grid').css('width', (100*x)+10+'px' );

        $('.grid').hide();
        $('#send').click(function(){
            $('.grid').slideDown(); 
        })              
        //Genere la grille    
        for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
            $('.grid').append('<div class="rowe'+i+'"></div>');
            for (var j = 1; j <= y; j++) {
                $('.rowe'+i).append('<div class="cell" id="cell'+i+'-'+j+'" ></div>');    
            }
        }    
        //PLacement Jetons &&  Previsualisation    
        $(document).on('click', '.cell', function () {
            if (color_count % 2 === 0) {
                var player1 = "red";
                color_count += 1;
            } else {
            // $(this).css("background-color" +player2);
            var player1 = 'yellow';
            color_count += 1;
            }
            $(this).css("background-color", player1);    
        })
    })
}
$('body').puissance4(7,6);
```

Sorry for the french commented lines.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `document.ready()` outside the function definition:

```
$.fn.puissance4 = function(x,y) {
    ̶$̶(̶d̶o̶c̶u̶m̶e̶n̶t̶)̶.̶r̶e̶a̶d̶y̶(̶(̶)̶ ̶=̶>̶ ̶{̶
      //Define puissance4 function
    ̶}̶)̶;̶
}

$(document).ready(() => {
    $('body').puissance4(7,6);
});
```